# How to declare optional global variable in robot script depending upon command line arguments in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a scenario where I need to set global variable in my robot script depending upon the command line arguments. In some cases, I can pass 2 arguments and in other 3 arguments from command line.

**sample.robot**

```
Set Global Variable  ${arg1}  ${ARG1}
Set Global Variable  ${arg2}  ${ARG2}
Set Global Variable  ${arg3}  ${ARG3}
```

**Scenario I**

Command line argument passed

```
robot --variable ARG1:arg1 --variable ARG2:arg2 sample.robot
```

During code execution, script throws an error that "Variable '${ARG3}' not found."

**Scenario II**

Command line argument passed

```
robot --variable ARG1:arg1 --variable ARG2:arg2 --variable ARG3:arg3 sample.robot
```

During code execution, everything works fine.

**Requirement**

What I need here is, even if I don't pass some command line arguments, it should not throw any error. Maybe some way to declare some global variable as optional and others as mandatory. Similar functionality can be achieved in python using "argparse" module.

Answer (score 0):

1. To set the global Variable in robot framework, you can use `Set Global Variable` builtin keyword from robot framework- You can see the reference [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable)
2. To study more on the command line options, you can go through this [link](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#all-command-line-options)
3. To get read the variable bu you want to have one default values set if there is no command-line argument is provided

`${value} =    Get Variable Value    &{var}    default value  #Set your default value here`

And now use a list or dict variable to dynamically hold varying numbers of arguments. Hence, if there is no command-line argument is provided for that suite.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you want to insert a specific set of data given a particular test scenario. If this is the case I'd recommend looking into Robot Framework [Variable Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files). In these external files you can craft all types of variables. They can easily be replaced by one that matches your test scenario.

If this all has to happen on the command line, then combining a single file name/path on the command line with the BuiltIn keyword: [Import Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables) should allow you the same sort of flexibility.